# adjust map to make 2 points visible

Tags: android, google-maps

I have 2 LatLng, usually a few kilometers apart, and I want to zoom map such that both points are visible. My code below sometimes works, sometimes not (map is zoomed to level 3 then). I think the reason is that the loop is too fast for the map to make the necessary adjustments in time.
Is there a way to wait for the map to update before making the test again? To note that process runs on UI thread

```
double x1=from.latitude;
double x2= to.latitude;
double x1half=(x1+x2)/2;
x1=from.longitude;
x2= to.longitude;
double x2half=(x1+x2)/2;
LatLng pp=new LatLng(x1half, x2half);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pp));//3.0
//now zoom map so that both points are in

double zoom=21;//V3.3
while(zoom>2){//
    map.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( (float) zoom ) ); 
    if(isCurrentLocationVisible(from,map)&&isCurrentLocationVisible(to,map)) return;
    /now we know map is still not visible.   give it a bit more room
    zoom--;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advice you to use the [newLatLngBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int%29) instead..You can create your bounds from your two geo points with the [LatLngBounds.builder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html).

To the second part of your question..You could do somethink like `map.post(new Runnable..)` which could solve the concurrency issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LatLngBounds like the following:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(locationOne);
        builder.include(locationTwo);
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,screen width, screen height, padding);
        map.moveCamera(cu);
```